# Bluetooth simply application

Tags: android

I want to ask you about some bluetooth library which I can use to implement simply application. I want to connect two devices by bluetooth. In application I want to have two buttons and I want to send from one device to second device by bluetooth which button was push. How I can do that? Any idea or tutorials can recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

In the Android developer page there is a good Bluetooth chat example, with source code. Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) to download the Example.

Then I suggest you the following tutorials:

[Bluetooth tutorial](http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/)

[Add demo](http://letitbit.net/download/19347.172fecf1b1790bfbd64b4d2115a6/sendobject.rar.html)